# Garbage Collection Not work in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, garbage-collection

i am working on the single page web application using angularJs.In My application when i go to each and every page cpu memory increased consistentely.I try with $destroy  , Remove console and unbind the window event.but till i get the same error.How to resolve it?

Comment: It's not very likely that anybody can help unless you provide any examples of your code with memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

you probably got some leak and its not related to angularjs.
$destroy is the right event to clean things up like window/document level bindings as you wrote, but you probably have other issues.
look in chrome profilers tab in the developer tools. it has ability to record what actions took most cpu, where memory is at and so on... very good tool.
you could use that to compare to runs of the same navigation to see what was added to the second run compared to the first.